# Rich Snippets via Schema.org Implemented Via JSON+LD But Not Being Picked Up By Crawler

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, google-rich-snippets, json-ld

We've implemented rich snippets for a product type, as well as rich snippets for the organization type.

Both types have their attributes passed into a JSON+LD type script wrapper.

**Please see the markup and validation here: [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.jomashop.com%252Fpanerai-luminor-men-watch-pam00104.html&filter=RICH_SNIPPETS_PRODUCTS)**

Google picks up the organization type and this is verifiable because we've actually changed the logo on our organization card.

***However, Google has not picked up any of the rich snippets attributes for our products.***

**Note** Both the product snippet and organization snippet validate perfectly, without any errors or warnings on the Structured Data Testing Tool. I do not think this is an issue with markup unless there is something instrinsically wrong with JSON+LD formatted rich snippets (as opposed to the inline markup variety)

**Additional Note** These JSON+LDs have been printed inside all of our product pages (30,000+) for well over 3 months now, with no change. This is most likely not an issue of time to propagate.

**Further Note** We are a very heavily trafficked website that Google shows respect to in search results. So I do not think that obscurity is the cause.

So, my question is: ***What are some possible reasons the above linked JSON+LD markup is failing? Is it possible that Google is intentionally ignoring it? What are some potential solutions to solving this issue?***

Comment: At present, if you want listed, drop JSON-LD and use schema.org microdata or RDFa format.

Comment: Don't drop anything, use them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2016:** The documentation got updated and it no longer contains the note. So now JSON-LD seems to be supported for the Products Rich Snippet.

---

In Google’s [Products Rich Snippet documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products), it is [noted for single product pages](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products#single_product_page) that the JSON-LD syntax is not yet fully supported:

> We are in the process of implementing JSON-LD support for this Rich Snippet type. At the current time, we recommend using microdata or RDFa.

This might explain why it’s (currently) not working.

([Apparently this note was added a few weeks ago.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/84372/17633))

Comment: No kidding!  Will look this over.  Why on earth would they publish this months ago without full support. I guess we are super early adopters.

Comment: @DavidLerner: I have no first-hand experience with JSON-LD + Google’s Product Rich Snippet, but the fact that their documentation was published for a long time without this note, and that we hadn’t any questions about such a problem (as far as I remember) in that time, *could* mean that it worked with JSON-LD at some point. Maybe they noticed a problem and deactivated support for now? Just a guess.

Comment: Makes sense. I've scoured the entire ecommerce world looking for a JSON+LD implementation without any luck,  though. Everyone else is still using inline, good relations,  etc.

Comment: Anyways, thanks. Still enough time before holiday season to get us indexed with schema.

Comment: Bad move on Google developer relations, removing the validation tool that validates microdata and RDFa and replacing it with a JSON-LD validator whose valid markup cannot be displayed in search results.

Comment: @pxwise it's working now, that warning about Products via JSON-LD is no longer on the page, and search results for my site are showing prices + In Stock.  Looks like it's been enabled some time in the last few months.

Comment: @therefromhere yeah it went live for me second week of January