# How to mark data using schema.org and JSON-LD on a website's home page

Tags: html, schema.org, json-ld

Recently i read a lot about marking structured data using schema.org, the first question is , is it recommended to use `json-ld` at all? because it seems to be new and is not fully supported yet.
My second question is on a home page or archive pages ( generally the pages that we have more than 1 article or product or blog post in them ) how do i use schema.org? for example for a page like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blog Home Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Blog title</h1>


        <!-- this needs schema.org -->
        <article>
            <h2>Article title</h2>
            Writtem by <span>Authorname</span> on <time datetime="">21 april</time>

            <p>
                Some text
            </p>

            Rated : 
            <div class="star-rate">
                <span class="star full">
                <span class="star full">
                <span class="star full">
                <span class="star half">
                <span class="star empty">
            </div>

            By <span>5</span> users.
        </article>

        <article>
            <h2>Article title</h2>
            Writtem by <span>Authorname</span> on <time datetime="">21 april</time>

            <p>
                Some text
            </p>

            Rated : 
            <div class="star-rate">
                <span class="star full">
                <span class="star full">
                <span class="star full">
                <span class="star half">
                <span class="star empty">
            </div>

            By <span>5</span> users.
        </article>
        <!-- and more articles to go -->
    </body>
</html>
```

How can i mark structured data using josn-ld and how to relate json objects to `<article>` tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some consumers support JSON-LD, some don’t. There can’t be a general answer to this, it depends on which consumers/features you want to support. For example, the consumer Google [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28612357/1591669) JSON-LD for some of their features, but [doesn’t support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32900171/1591669) it for some of their other features.

If you have multiple entities on a page (like your two articles from the example), you’d simply provide multiple nodes. There are various ways how to achieve this:

- You could provide a [separate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30730343/1591669) `script` element for each node:

  ```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "CreativeWork"
  }
  </script>

  <script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "CreativeWork"
  }
  </script>
  ```
- You could provide one `script` element and use an array as value for `@graph` (sharing the `@context` for all nodes):

  ```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@graph": 
    [
      {
         "@type": "CreativeWork"
      },
      {
         "@type": "CreativeWork"
      }
    ]
  }
  </script>
  ```

To allow others to differentiate the nodes (and make their own statements about them), you could give each node a URI with the [`@id` keyword](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#node-identifiers).

Comment: Thank you for your answer , about the `@id` thing , the URI must be the permalink to the article , right?

Comment: @farscode: It depends on if you care about the *httpRange-14 issue* ([see my explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669)) or not. For providing the permalink to a page about the node, you could use [Schema.org’s `url` property](http://schema.org/url) in both cases. If you care about httpRange-14, you might want to provide another URI in `@id`, if you don’t care about it you might want to omit `@id` or use the same URI (which you are using in the `url` property). -- If you know RDF: the URL in `@id` is the *subject* of the triple, the URL in `schema:url` is the *object*.