# Schema.org: What to use, Microdata or JSON-LD?

Tags: markup, schema.org, microdata, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

The data markup [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) for search sites like Google, Yahoo!, Bing and Yandex is great for snippets. However, I perceive that most of webmasters use Microdata and almost never use [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/). I learned about JSON-LD recently and I have some doubts:

Could I use it without compability problems with search engine?

Comment: For your second question (which I removed, because it’s not closely related to your central question), see the question: [How to move JSON-LD from in-line to in-a-file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33236198/1591669)

Comment: What about accepting this awesome answer?

Answer (score 1):

There can’t be a general answer:

- Each consumer (search engine, tool, etc.) has its own conditions (what it supports for which feature).
- Each syntax (JSON-LD, Microdata, RDFa, etc.) has its own advantages and disadvantages.

Specific example to illustrate the problem: Google [recommends](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/schema-org) to use JSON-LD for some of their features, but doesn’t support it for some others (e.g., [for their Products Rich Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32900171/1591669)).

For what it’s worth, [JSON-LD](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/) and [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-html-rdfa-20150317/) are both W3C Recommendations (while Microdata is [part of WHATWG’s Living HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#microdata), but [no longer under development at W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/)). So if you care about this, you might want to consider using RDFa instead of Microdata (see [my comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669)). RDFa and JSON-LD are, of course, quite different: with JSON-LD you’d have to duplicate your content, while you can reuse it with RDFa.