# How to add schema.org microdata into wapka

Tags: schema.org, microdata

Hy am using wapka.mobi since i can't afford a host. Please how can i add the schema.org into my webpages. Note: I can't add anything to my body tag like `< body itemprop="BLAH BLAH BLAH" >`  please any help?

Comment: What *can* you add/change, if you can’t edit your HTML?

Comment: @unor what i mean is that I can't edit the <code><b0dy></code> of my site. But i can add anything below the **body tag**. What I also mean is that i can't declare the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have to use the `body` element to add Microdata. You may add Microdata attributes [to all HTML5 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889900/1591669).

```html
<body>
  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <!-- … -->
  </article>
</body>
```

If your software doesn’t allow to add Microdata attributes at all, you could consider using JSON-LD instead. You only have to add a `script` element with `type="application/ld+json"`.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BlogPosting"
}
</script>
```

Comment: does <code>s c r i p t element with t y p e = " a p p l i c a t l d + j s o n "</code> work on all platforms.

Comment: owk agreed that i used the **json** how can i name the **itemprop** like name of article,author, link and the rest.

Comment: @MrJay: JSON-LD (in a `script` element) is one of the three syntaxes supported by the Schema.org sponsors (the other two syntaxes are Microdata and RDFa). However, each consumer decides which syntaxes to support ([Google, for example, recommends JSON-LD for some of their features, but doesn’t support it for others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34245691/1591669)). -- Here’s a [JSON-LD example](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/81287/17633) that shows how to specify a Schema.org property (`url` in this case).